# Warning: move_uploaded_file(myfiles/img.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello i have some issues with my file uploading at localhost. I am using XAMPP. I have looked at php.ini and ensured file_uploads = On, but the warnings won't disappear and the files don't get uploaded. Furthermore i have tried to look at some of the other pages with the same topic without luck.

My errors:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(myfiles/img.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/changethesettings.php on line 118

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpRGfg7t' to 'myfiles/img.jpg' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/changethesettings.php on line 118
```

this is my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="changethesettings.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit file"/>
</form>
```

This is my PHP code (changethesettings.php):

```
        $target_dir = "myfiles/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    -> line 118    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }


die("<br> the end");
```

It should be mentioned that i have a .htaccess. I don't know if that might be the cause of the warning:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Options -Indexes
```

Thanks

Comment: No sorry sir. Nope

Comment: are you sure you have permission to write to folder? in this case you need also add permission to the folder itself so the user using the PHP can write to it

Comment: Thanks sir. Forgot to enable that. Thanks. It's sad that such a small error can cause that annoying issues. It works now that i have changed the user privileges to read and writing.